# PDF page break background colour

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am forcing a page break in a webpage using the CSS property `page-break-after: always;` and then converting the page to PDF using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 with the additional args "--footer-center [page]/[topage] --margin-top 0 --margin-right 0 --margin-left 0". After the page break the background is grey, which I need to remove as the PDF will be printed. I have attempted to fix the issue using CSS background colour which did not have an effect on the background after the page break. I have also tried using wkhtmltopdf args to change the page margins which removes the grey background but messes up the page layout. Please see below image of the problem.

[image: PDF Issue]